# how can i synchronize wordpress between local side and remote side?

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress in my free web space, and also intalled it in my local pc.
I have  to write blog in local wordpress  when  can't  get  web.
How to synchronize  wordpress  between local  and remote side ? 
which plugin can i download to do the job?
should i write some php code to synchronize wordpress?

I can do the job by hand,export my blog in the xml format file from remote wordpress in which i installed on my free web space,and import the exported xml format file into my local wordpress,can i do that job automatically?

Comment: Question is not clear yet.. Would you like to Export the post to live blog?

Comment: Start a research from here: [How to Mirror WordPress database from Remote server to Local server](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18609)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Wordpress plugin called Database Sync which lets you sync your WP database across multiple servers like Dev, QA and Production. But it doesn't let you sync your uploaded files.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/database-sync/

You could use a FTP synchronization software to keep your uploaded files synced. I use WinSCP for that.